# Video conversion from 720p to 480p JPEG - FPGA

Tags: image-processing, fpga

I want to ask if conversion from 720p JPEG image to 480p JPEG is easier, faster and require less LEs(and also if it's possible) then converting an image from RGB RAW to 480p. This using an FPGA. I tought about two possibilities, crop image or delete some vertical and horizontal rows and then compact image. Since JPEG compression from RGB require a lot of LEs and space on FPGA, reduce an image already compressed may be easier? If not, crop images on fpga it's possible in JPEG compression?

Answer (score 0):

JPEG's entropy data can't be seek, i.e. you don't know where line number 16 begins in the stream until you decoded all the previous lines/pixels.

To do what you want, you would have to entropy decode the first JPEG, keep the macroblocks that you want and entropy encode the result. It's likely to take less resources than a full JPEG encoder.

Note that some JPEG use restart intervals. These allow you to seek the JPEG stream at some predefined interval. If you know your input JPEG has those and that you have enough granularity, it may be possible to do what you want without the entropy coding/decoding.